# Notepad++ code outline as Eclipse's outline

Tags: notepad++, eclipse, source-code, outline

Folding and unfolding blocks of code helps, but in bigger files I really want to have the outline overview of a class and its methods.

So, is there a plugin or anything for Notepad++ that I can have a outline of a class as the outline tab on Eclipse?

Comment: In notepad++ v6.6.8, you just select "View | Function List" and it works great.

Answer (score 9):

Function List plugin was great, but it has not been maintained for a long time and has been reported unstable for a while now. (As I'm writting, the actual version of Notepad++ is 6.1.7)

You should try [SourceCookifier](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/) which can be found on it's sourceforge page or better, directly in the Notepad++ Plugin Manager.

By the way, in the View menu, you've got an option to collapse different levels of your code which can then be unfold manually.

Hope this helps, happy coding mate.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like a job for the [Function List](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Function%20List/FunctionList%20Plugin%20v2.1/) plugin.

To install it, simply follow the instructions in `install.txt` inside of the `.zip` file.

It doesn't appear to work with Java out of the box, but you can follow [this guide](http://randronov.blogspot.com/2010/02/howto-list-all-my-functions-in-csharp-c.html) to make it work properly. Alternatively, you can manually add the following to the configuration XML file, inside of the Java section:

```
<Group name="METHOD" subgroup="" icon="0" child="0" autoexp="0" matchcase="1" fendtobbeg="" bbegtobend="\{" keywords="">
    <Rules regexbeg="\w*[\s\*]*" regexfunc="\w+\s*[\s\*]*" regexend="\(.*\)" bodybegin="\{" bodyend="\}" sep="" />
</Group>
```

Comment: Python example: http://blog.theroyweb.com/function-list-plugin-part-2-python-parsing-rules

Answer (score 2):

In Notepad++ v7.5,
**Choose View-> Function List** 
[image]